# Having problems starting with Antlr

Tags: parsing, antlr

I would consider myself as being moderately experienced with the whole topic of lexing/parsing, having written small ones myself and tried yacc / unicc and some DSLs like xtext, ohm-js. These all were more or less straightforward after catching up with the basics but ANTLR really makes my head ache.

I've got several weird error messages, so started to break my grammar down to a bare minimum to track them but now I hit a wall again (probably a very stupid mistake as always, of course, but I don't seem to find it right now..)

Here is my Grammar.g4:
...

```
sourceFile  : Statement+ ;
Statement   : FuncDef | VarDef ;
FuncDef     : 'function' IDENT '(' ')' BlockDef ;
VarDef      : 'var' IDENT ';' ;
BlockDef    : '{' Statement* '}' ;
IDENT       : CHAR (CHAR | DIGIT)* ;
CHAR        : [a-zA-Z_] ;
DIGIT       : [0-9] ;
WS          : [ \t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

...

Trying to match `function hello() { }` gives the following:

...

```
$> function hello() { }
line 1:0 mismatched input 'function' expecting Statement
line 1:14 token recognition error at: '('
line 1:15 token recognition error at: ')'
line 1:17 token recognition error at: '{ '
line 1:19 token recognition error at: '}'
$>
```

...

The linked listener function is not called, unlike with a bigger grammar - basing on the same small one! - which always complained about a mismatch at hello - `line 1:9 mismatched input '`hello`' expecting IDENT` but then the listener **is** triggered.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: In ANTLR, you *must* use lowercase for non-terminals. Tokens start with upper case letters, and the parsing rules are different. (In yacc/bison, it's just a convention. Lemon also makes it obligatory. IMHO, it's a good habit.)

Comment: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md (second paragraph)

Comment: Find an existing grammar for ANTLR 4 and then start from it, https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4 In that way you can avoid quite a lot of pains.

Answer (score 1):

In ANTLR, you *must* use lowercase for non-terminals. Tokens start with upper case letters, and the parsing rules are different.

See https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md, especially the second paragraph. (Also the section on lexer fragments in that page.)

Comment: Thanks for that! Indeed I remember reading it but forgot about cause in the Listener (for easier reading purposes) the rules begin with a capital letter, e.g. enterFuncdef for rule funcdef. 

Now it forks as purposed. Guess I'll have to read the Definitive Antlr Reference instead of just skim through it :)

Maybe do you know of any intermediate level interpreter/transpiler/compiler projects using Antlr and don't just showcase the parser but also actual using of the parsed text through listener or walker?